# Play 2.5 Filters

Tags: java, playframework-2.5

I am trying to migrate to play 2.5 from 2.4.  I am facing issues in filter code. Below is my filter code

```
public class Filters implements HttpFilters {

    private final SecurityFilter securityFilter;

    @Inject
    public Filters(SecurityFilter securityFilter) {
        this.securityFilter = securityFilter;
    }

    @Override
    public EssentialFilter[] filters() {
        return new EssentialFilter[] {securityFilter.asJava()};
    }
}
```

According to documentation https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaHttpFilters

asJava() method is available, and compiles perfectly in eclipse with 2.5 jar. But **above code fails when I run through activator ui or activator dist**.

I have updated the plugins.sbt with below 
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.5.1")

But it still fails. What else should be changed? or Is there any other configuration to be changed?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I am getting error saying asJava() is not a valid method!!!

Comment: From where are you importing `SecurityFilter`? Is it a Scala filter?

Comment: import play.http.HttpFilters;
import play.mvc.EssentialFilter;    are the imports. But the security filter itself looks like written in scala from pac4j its import is import org.pac4j.play.filters.SecurityFilter;

Comment: @Guruprasad did you figure out how to resolve this

Answer (score 0):

when im migrate my application from 2.4 to 2.5 i have the same problem and i solved that way:

i change the filters code to:

```
import play.filters.cors.CORSFilter;
import play.http.DefaultHttpFilters;

import javax.inject.Inject;

public class Filters extends DefaultHttpFilters {

@Inject public Filters(CORSFilter corsFilter) {
    super(corsFilter);
}
```

And follow the steps in documentation: [Enabling the CORS filter](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/CorsFilter)

Add in build.sbt

> libraryDependencies += **filters**

And configure cors in application.conf:

```
filters{
# CORS filter configuration
cors {

  # The path prefixes to filter.
  pathPrefixes = ["/json/rest/api"]

  # The allowed origins. If null, all origins are allowed.
  allowedOrigins = null

  # The allowed HTTP methods. If null, all methods are allowed
  allowedHttpMethods = ["POST","GET"]

  # The allowed HTTP headers. If null, all headers are allowed.
  allowedHttpHeaders = null

  # The exposed headers
  exposedHeaders = []

  # Whether to support credentials
  supportsCredentials = true

  # The maximum amount of time the CORS meta data should be cached by the client
  preflightMaxAge = 1 hour
}
```

Feel free to ask any questions.